# How to calculate size of UILabel according to the text in Swift

Tags: ios, uilabel

I need to adjust the size of the UILabel according to its size dynamically, width may be constant but height should be dynamic

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: yes I am using autolayout

Comment: If you are using autolayout, then don,t just give height constraint, label will automatically resized according to the text assigned. other constraints will be according to your placement, wherever you wanna place it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 0, width: curWidth!, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    label.font = curFont!
    label.sizeToFit();
```